# DB2 Timestamp select statement

Tags: db2, timestamp

I am trying to run a simple query which gets me data based on timestamp, as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table_name> 
WHERE id = 1 
AND usagetime = timestamp('2012-09-03 08:03:06') 
WITH UR;
```

This does not seem to return a record to me, whereas this record is present in the database for id = 1.

What am I doing wrong here?

The datatype of the column usagetime is correct, set to timestamp.

Comment: Timestamps have fractions of a second, as well. I'm guessing that's your problem, I don't see those in your select statement.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@bhamby is correct. By leaving the microseconds off of your timestamp value, your query would only match on a usagetime of 2012-09-03 08:03:06.000000

If you don't have the complete timestamp value captured from a previous query, you can specify a ranged predicate that will match on any microsecond value for that time:

```
...WHERE id = 1 AND usagetime BETWEEN '2012-09-03 08:03:06' AND '2012-09-03 08:03:07'
```

or

```
...WHERE id = 1 AND usagetime >= '2012-09-03 08:03:06' 
   AND usagetime < '2012-09-03 08:03:07'
```

Comment: I also wanted to point out that the call to the TIMESTAMP() is unnecessary when specifying an acceptable string representation of a timestamp value (which you did properly in your question).

Comment: Please never use `BETWEEN`, especially when dealing with date/time/timestamps.  For one thing, your two `WHERE` clauses are **NOT** equivalent.

Comment: You're correct. The `BETWEEN` condition would include the following second, but the two comparisons would exclude the following second. 

Another downside of using `BETWEEN` is that - at least in older versions of DB2 - the query optimizer has been known to choose a less efficient access plan than it does for the two explicit ranged comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use TRUNC function on your column when comparing with string format, so it compares only till seconds, not milliseconds.

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE id = 1 
AND TRUNC(usagetime, 'SS') = '2012-09-03 08:03:06';
```

If you wanted to truncate upto minutes, hours, etc. that is also possible, just use appropriate notation instead of 'SS':

```
hour ('HH'), minute('MI'), year('YEAR' or 'YYYY'), month('MONTH' or 'MM'), Day ('DD')
```