# Date inside current timestamp - IBM DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a column (ROW_UPDATE_TIME) in a table where it stores the **timestamp** when an update happens in this table.

I'd like to know how to check rows that the timestamp is today.
This is what I'm using now, but it's not a pretty solution I think:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    ROW_UPDATE_TIME BETWEEN (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 1 DAY) AND (CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 1 DAY);
```

Is there a better solution, example: ROW_UPDATE_TIME = CURRENT DATE, or something like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DB2 Timestamp select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251802/db2-timestamp-select-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    DATE(ROW_UPDATE_TIME) = CURRENT DATE;
```

Comment: This may be a "prettier" solution, but it will likely perform worse, especially if you expect index-based access.

Answer (score 0):

The first version you have provided will not return you the results you expect, because you will get in the result timestamps from today or tomorrow, depends on the hour you run it.

Use the query below to get the results from today:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    row_update_time
        BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE,'00:00:00')
        AND TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE,'23:59:59')
```

Avoid applying a function to a column you compare in the where clause(`DATE(row_update_time) = CURRENT_DATE`) . That will cause the optimizer to run the function against each row, just to allocate the data you need. It could slow down the query dramatically. Try to run explain against the two versions and you will see what I mean.

Comment: This is also wrong, because the `TIMESTAMP` type has fractional seconds.  This answer essentially skips the last second of the day.